# Access SpringBoardServices.h method in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone-privateapi

I downloaded SpringBoardServices.h file given in SpringBoardServices and added it to my project. But how to access one of the method present inside SpringBoardServices.h file. I am trying to call **BOOL SBSProcessIDForDisplayIdentifier(CFStringRef identifier, pid_t *pid);** this method present inside SpringBoardServices.h from MyClass.m file. How to call above method from my .m file?

I used below approach, but it is returning null.
    Class myclass = NSClassFromString(@"SpringBoardServices");
    NSLog(@" myclass %@", myclass); //null
    id myobj = [[myclass alloc] init];

I downloaded SpringBoardServices.h file from this [link](https://github.com/Cykey/ios-reversed-headers/blob/master/SpringBoardServices/SpringBoardServices.h).

Comment: Do you know the difference between c and objective-c?

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of methods to access C methods from private framework:

**Method 1:**

- Link a private framework (similar to the way how you link public framework)
- Include .h file
- Do a call:

SBSProcessIDForDisplayIdentifier(...)

**Method 2:**

- Load framework in runtime using dlopen
- Find a method using dlsym
- Do a call

BTW. This is applicable to C method's and second method won't work for ObjectiveC methods.

Comment: I tried Method 1. But it is giving "Typedef redefinition with different types" error.

Comment: Where does it show it? I remember, I had to do some cleanup of .h files after they were generated by class-dump-z. As example, I had to remove something like "#import <NSObject.h>"